# How can I solve Laplace Tranformation of $1/s^{5/2}$?

Tags: laplace-transform, laplacian, inverse-laplace, laplace-method, laplace-expansion

I have just started Laplace Transformation

And I came across a problem which contains $1/s^{5/2}$

How to solve it? I know $\mathcal L\{t^n\}= n!/s^{n+1}$

Please say how to solve it.

Comment: When $n$ is not an integer. Replace $n!$ with Gamma function $\Gamma(n+1)=\int_0^\infty x^ne^{-x}\mathrm dx$

Answer (score 1):

Using TravorLZH's idea we have for $x>-1$,

\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}\{t^x\}&=\int_0^\infty t^xe^{-st}dt,\quad\text{doing }u=st\\
&=\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{u}{s}\right)^xe^{-u}\frac{du}{s}\\
&=\frac{1}{s^{x+1}}\int_0^\infty u^xe^{-u}du\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{s^{x+1}}
\end{align*}

Taking $x+1=5/2\Rightarrow x=3/2$. We have
$$
\mathcal{L}\{t^{3/2}\}=\frac{\Gamma(3/2)}{s^{5/2}}=\frac{\frac{3}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\Gamma(1/2)}{s^{5/2}}=\frac{3}{4}\cdot\sqrt\pi\cdot\frac{1}{s^{5/2}}
$$
Therefore it is easy to conclude that
$$
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{1}{s^{5/2}}\right\}=\frac{4\cdot t^{3/2}}{3\cdot\sqrt\pi}.
$$